# How to be convincing searching for a new job after a short period of time?

Tags: interviewing

I'm currently applying for jobs after spending just 8 months in the old one. In the current company I've been bullied from the very beginning (I've been given contradictory tasks and punished for doing any of the alternatives or trying to clarify; shouted at and punished for what I was able to prove on the basis of emails not to be true). I have told myself I need to stay a few months to have a good CV.

I've tried to solve that by talking constructively, talking and explaining things. But it's not a conflict on a rational level. My boss simply hates me and he will do everything to prove me I'm sh*.

And I just can't anymore.

Add to that the fact that the company is so extremely disorganised that I'm simply not able to do my tasks, the fact that the company has a culture I don't accept ("Let's change everything and take long-term decisions as soon as possible without any analysis or consideration for consequences. Analysis is stupid") and the fact that I'm actually paid lower than I should be paid on my level on experience (I accepted the job hoping for a new atmosphere and interesting tasks).

Of course I can't mention that during job interviews.

What should I say in order not to sound "negative"? From my experience I know that companies dig quite deep and if I say that "I receive plenty of operational tasks, although the position I've accepted was a project position" they don't accept that as a valid reason.

Answer (score 2):

Here's where the dreaded buzzphrase about "a good fit" can come in handy -

> My current position has a greater focus on BAU operational tasks then was originally posited and as project-orientated work is where I'm keen to focus my career I don't feel that the current role is the right fit for me.

The language here is not overtly negative, you aren't saying that you won't do *any* operational work and 8 months is a reasonable length of time to ascertain that the makeup of tasks you are getting is representative of the role so you aren't someone who cuts and runs at the first thing that doesn't go your way.

Comment: Thanks! And if I said that I have a new boss (which is true), with a completely different work style and vision for the unit. Does it sound ok to your ears? It's just that I've had bad experiences with mentioning operational tasks.

Comment: @user3952 Would you have a good answer if they ask "What do you mean by 'different work style and vision'? What's your work style? What would your vision have been"?